# php graph timestamp not reading php time() as numbers

Tags: php

I was wondering how I can fix my graph so that I can read epochtime. Here is the code:

```
$graphTime = time();    
for($graphTime = 29; $graphTime >= 0; $graphTime--){    
    $timestamp = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j") - $graphTime, date("Y"));     
    $set = date("Y.m.d", $timestamp);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE timestamp = '$set");
```

SQL Database:

```
  Timestamp : 2014.05.01
```

Basically I wanted to change it from reading my timestamp as `2014.05.01` to reading my timestamp as php time `1398967062`. I already tried setting the WHERE to statement in the query to `$timestamp`. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why do you set `$graphTime = time()` and then use the same variable for the iteration in the `for` loop?

Comment: easiest when having 2 graphs in one page

Comment: But your `for` loop is overwriting the variable. After it's done `$graphTime` is set to 0, not `time()`.

Comment: so leaving it but how are you checking it with time?

Comment: How come I can not set my `$graphTime` in my `WHERE` statement like this `WHERE timestamp = '$graphTime'` ?

Comment: How come you ask a question that I already answered below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL timestamp strings are `yyyy-mm-dd`. So your `.` version is invalid. Plus your query has syntax errors:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE timestamp = '$set");    
                                                                         ^--missing '
```

Try

```
$set = date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
$result = mysql_query("...... timestamp = '$set'");
```

instead

Comment: His database doesn't contain MySQL timestamps, it contains strings in the format YYYY.MM.DD.

Comment: Then `unixtimestamp(str_to_date(timestamp, "%Y.%m.%d")) = $php_time`, but that's just getting silly. date/time values should be stored as native mysql types, not strings, especially if you need to do any date math/comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for($day = 29; $day >= 0; $day--){    
    $graphTime = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("n"), date("j") - $day, date("Y"));     
    $set = date("Y.m.d", $graphTime);
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM user WHERE timestamp = '$set'");
```

UPDATE:

Based on your comments, I think you made a mistake when you said the database contains `YYYY.MM.DD` in the `timestamp` column. It sounds like it's an epoch time. So I think what you want is:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT timestamp - timestamp%86400 AS graphTime, COUNT(*) AS dailyCount
                       FROM user
                       WHERE timestamp >= UNIX_TIMESTAMP(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 29 DAY))
                       GROUP BY graphTime");
```

You don't need a PHP loop, this will return all the daily counts. `86400` is the number of seconds in a day, so `timestamp - timestamp%86400` is the epoch time for the beginning of each day.

Comment: How come I can not set my $graphTime in my WHERE statement like this `WHERE timestamp = '$graphTime'`

Comment: Because `$graphTime` is an epoch timestamp, not a string in the form `YYYY.MM.DD`.

Comment: The question says the database contains `2014.05.01`. That's a string, not an epoch timestamp.